# Can I have a View controller presented as form sheet and then later shoot to full screen view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a View controller which I want to present as a form sheet to the user first and if needed present it as full screen later on a button tap. I tried looking over for tutorials but did not find any ?

```
NewViewController *vc = [[NewViewController alloc]init];
    vc.delegate = self;
    id presentViewController;
    if(IPAD) {
        presentViewController = [self formSheetControllerWithVC:vc];
    }else {
        presentViewController = vc;
    }

    [self presentViewController:presentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In my NewViewController can I use a button or something to make it full screen ?